# How do I insert a function call inside img src?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display images from my database. I'm trying to call my `getImages()` function from inside my `output` function (both in same DBdata class) which outputs the properties from my database.
I just need this method to call from inside the `<img src=` line.

However, using `$this->getImages()` inside the `img src=` doesn't work and in fact PhpStorm throws an error saying "field getImages() not found in DBdata"... however `getImages()` ISN'T a field and it's a method.

Below is my code which I'm not sure if it will even output correctly yet so if you have a different way to do it please let me know.

`output()` method---- line `<img src=\"'.$this->getImages().'\" alt=\"\">` is where my error is.

```
public function output(){
    echo "   
        <div class=\"tab-pane fade show active\" id=\"horizental-post\" role=\"tabpanel\" aria-labelledby=\"horizental-tab\">
            <div class=\"sales-items horizental-view\">
                <div class=\"sale-item\">
                    <div class=\"row\">
                        <div class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4\">
                            <div class=\"item-img\">
                                <img src=\"'.$this->getImages().'\" alt=\"\">
                                <span class=\"item-status\">" . $this->status . "</span>
                                <a href=\"single_properties.php?id=". $this->id . "\" title=\"\" class=\"view-btn\">View</a>
                            </div><!--item-img end-->
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8\">
                            <div class=\"item-info\">
                                <h3><a href=\"single_properties.php?id=". $this->id . "\" title=\"\">" . $this->name . "</a></h3>
                                <span>" . $this->address . "</span>
                                <p>Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisielit quat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Morbi accumsan sum velit. </p>
                                <div class=\"specs-info\">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Beds: " . $this->beds . " </li>
                                        <li>Baths: " . $this->baths . "</li>
                                        <li>Sqft: " . $this->sqft . "</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <strong class=\"item-price\">£ " . $this->price . "</strong>
                                </div><!--specs-info end-->
                            </div><!--item-info end-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--sale-item end-->
            </div><!--sales-items end-->
        </div>
    ";
}
```

The `getImages()` method is:

```
public function getImages(){
    require_once("assets/database.php");
    $conn = new connectDB();
    $myDatabase = $conn->getConnectDB();
    $sqlQuery= "select image from images WHERE imageID = '". $this->id ."'";
    $data = $myDatabase->query($sqlQuery)->fetchAll()[0];
    $image = $data['image'];
    return '"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run the `getImages` function and save the return to a variable, before the `echo` in the `output` function the echo out the image base64 string

Comment: @a.mola For that he cannot find the image as function did not execute yet. Right?

Comment: Before the `echo` in the `output` function I typed in `$images = $this->getImages();` then called `$images` inside the img src tag. However, now on my website it says `Undefined index: image in DBdata line 280`. Line 280 is `$image = $data['image'];`. Does anyone have a better way to write my `getImages()` function? @a.mola

Comment: I think you must add `$images` inside your src tag as my experience in PHP. Or something similar to that.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I have done that, but it gives the error as said in my previous comment

Comment: @xzaman are you sure your WHERE SQL query matches some rows and returns the image column from the images table?

Comment: @a.mola The query works and returns the image as when I type the same query but instead of `'". $this->id ."'` I replaced it with `1055` as I know this contains an image.

Comment: @a.mola Originally the error said `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` but I assume that's because there is no image associated with that property. After deleting `[0]` on the end of ` $data = $myDatabase->query($sqlQuery)->fetchAll()[0]; ` it says the error `Undefined index: image in DBdata line 280` (same error as I stated before)... Nevertheless, I have kept it `[0]` in the line as it references index 0 in the array of images, BUT even for properties that have images, they aren't displaying the image but the index error still remains

Comment: I think its only by changing the quotes in the string though. Because its most likely the string concatenation

Comment: If you don't use the `[0]` its going to be an array of the results

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If PhpStorm already provides a hint, why not follow it?

Comment: That is one complex string... You have one quote wrong and  it may prevent execution of the PHP code! Are you even sure that the PHP code is being executed? This why we use 'templates'. If you insist on doing this then switch in and out of PHP mode in the function!  Run all the PHP code inside `<?php echo $this->yourFunction() ?>` tags. That way you stand some chance of debugging it. Also, it will be a lot easier to modify. PHP is a 'templating language' Please use it as such.

Comment: @NicoHaase I fixed the original problem of how to get my function to run inside the img src tag, as @a.mola helped with. Now the issue is I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 on line 278`. Line 278 is $data = `$myDatabase->query($sqlQuery)->fetchAll()[0];`. If I remove the index [0] from the end of the line then it points to the line below it `$images = $data['image'];` and says `Notice: Undefined index: image`. To my understanding it says undefined index 0 as there is no index 0 in the array. Which makes sense for some of my properties as they don't have images attached.

Comment: @RyanVincent The PHP code is being executed but it's just displaying undefined offset 0 since there is no image inside index 0 in the array. I want to insert the same image into all of the image ID's that are in the table, so I did `insert into images(image) values ('imgProperty608b49c85ce9b2.89409986');` However, since I have a foreign key to the imageID and propertyID of properties table it won't insert it. Should I remove the foreign key then add it back in after I've inserted it?